# Concurrent algorithm for interrupting and restarting a calculation

Tags: java, multithreading, concurrency, locks

I am developing an application which performs allows the user to adjust several parameters and then performs a computation which can take up to a minute, after which it displays the result to the user.

I would like the user to be able to adjust the parameters and restart the calculation, terminating the progress of the current calculation.

Additionally, from the programming perspective, I would like to be able to block until the calculation is completed or interrupted, and be able to know which.

In pseudo code, this is roughly what I am looking for:

```
method performCalculation:
    interrupt current calculation if necessary
    asynchronously perform calculation with current parameters

method performCalculationBlock:
    interrupt current calculation if necessary
    perform calculation with current parameters
    if calculation completes:
        return true
    if calculation is interrupted:
        return false
```

What I have so far satisfies the first method, but I am not sure how to modify it to add the blocking functionality:

```
private Thread computationThread;
private Object computationLock = new Object();
private boolean pendingComputation = false;

...

public MyClass() {
    ...

    computationThread = new Thread() {
        public void run() {
            while (true) {
                synchronized (computationLock) {
                    try {
                        computationLock.wait();
                        pendingComputation = false;
                        calculate();
                    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        private void checkForPending() throws InterruptedException {
            if (pendingComputation)
                throw new InterruptedException();
        }

        private void calculate() {
            ...
            checkForPending();
            ...
            checkForPending();
            ...
            // etc.
        }
    };
    computationThread.start();
}

private void requestComputation() {
    pendingComputation = true;
    synchronized (computationLock) {
        computationLock.notify();
    }
}
```

What is the best way to go about adding this functionality? Or is there a better way to design the program to accomplish all of these things?

Answer (score 1):

If you are using JDK 5 or earlier, check the java.util.concurrent package. The FutureTask class seems to match your requirement: a cancellable asynchronous computation with blocking feature.

Comment: This definitely looks like the direction I want to go, and I've got it somewhat working, but I'm having trouble cancelling the current computation. Would you be able to provide a short code sample?